# Seem to be losing a day in date conversions

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, date, time

So as the title says, I keep losing a day as I go from mysql to my javascript and I cant figure it out. You lose a day when you insert into the data base (let's say I put 10/14/12 the database will read 10/13/12) and I also lose a day when I read from the database (I fetch the 10/13/12 and it now reads 10/12/12).

Here is my process:

```
//date input from jquery ui datepicker       
$('#datepicker'+p).datepicker({numberOfMonths: 3, showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: "D, d M, yy"});

//date sent to php to upload to mysql so there is a format conversion
$start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startdate));
```

Now on to downloading:

```
 //date taken from mysql no modifications

//date modified to be sent to viewer in a nicer format
var start = $.datepicker.formatDate('D, d M, yy', new Date (item.start));
```

What I think: the issue seems to happen both ways and I am pretty sure my javascript is not the issue and because there is only php conversion one way that seems to rule out both. Could this be an issue with my mysql server? ALSO NOTE that the dates are saved in mysql as type DATE!

```
//as requested my sql code
 INSERT INTO classdates (start, end, hours, days, off, notes, type, branch) VALUES(:start, :end, :hours, :days, :off, :notes, :type, :branch)
```

Comment: You haven't shown *how* you're inserting or fetching the date into MySQL.

Comment: also this happens on the way to mysql and from so it cant be an inserting issue.

Comment: What type of server are you running? You need to go a little deeper and verify the datetime that your server has set. In Ubuntu (and other *nix servers) you can do "date" from the command line. I recently had an issue where ntp wasn't syncing my server time.

Comment: I have a hosting though Godaddy.. how can I look up that information? Is there php code?

Comment: This could also be a time zone issue.

Comment: ok so i got the date from the server, its 13/10/2012 and my date right now is the 14th. How can I fix this?

Comment: but this does not explain why my date that i am entering is being changed? I am not relying on the timezone.. I am providing the date not generating it.

Comment: @user860869: If it "happens on the way to mysql" that sounds like it *is* an inserting issue. If the database isn't the database you think you were inserting, the problem's there...

Comment: then what explains what happens when I am reading from the database? The date I get there is short a day as well (so 2 days short of what i initially tied to insert)

Comment: dump the value just before the INSERT to see if it's the PHP or the database becuase i suspect strtotime() function as it produces UNIX timestamp and has some quirks in the data string parsing.

Comment: the date is correct right before going into the database..so the variable entered into the database is the correct date but what the database shows after insertion is wrong... could this have something to do with the field type `Date` that is the only thing that makes sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue was the javascript `new Date() function`. It is not just converting the date but also manipulating it. I had to accommodate for the timezone change.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to unixtime on client side (javascript),  then insert it with `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP()` to mysql table. it will allow you to safe convert clent's time to server time.

Comment: how about going from the server to the client how can i fix that issue? And could this really be the issue to losing two days? Wouldn't the lost day be regained or at least maintained when fetching? Why am i losing an additional day when fetching?

Comment: all i could say - if you operate unixtime - you are safe, also you are safe if you operate date in rfc-2822 format, in any other cases it could be absolute unxepected results when you dealing with date